# Getting an error with Jekyll serve

Tags: jekyll

Have basically nothing but a _config.yml and index.md file, and when running jekyll serve I'm getting this:

D, [2015-07-08T10:33:29.810161 #14194] DEBUG -- : Celluloid 0.17.0 is running in BACKPORTED mode. [ http://git.io/vJf3J ]
jekyll 2.5.3 | Error:  wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Please help!

Comment: The site gets built, but watching doesn't work because of this error :(

Comment: if you do jekyll new mysite does that site work? I'd guess this is not an error in jekyll, but something wrong with ruby or something. What OS?

Comment: Nope :( same thing happens on a new project created that way...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure this is the answer for you since I wasn't using Jekyll but I had the same error when I was trying to use compass watch.

Rolling back both Celluloid and Listen did the trick for me.

I added the following to my gemfile:

gem 'listen', '<2.10.0'

gem 'compass', '<0.17.0'